# Escaping jquery update div

Tags: jquery

I have a `<p>` tag that updates on `.keyup` from a textarea.

```
$("textarea").keyup(function(e) {
            var newtext = $("textarea").val().replace(/\n/g,'<br/>');
            $("p").html(newtext);

        });
```

How do I escape javascript that a user enters.

I don't want to escape the html just the javascript.

Comment: Check now the answer, I've updated the code to match

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using

```
$("p").html(newtext);
```

you could use

```
$("p").text(newtext);
```

It's a [function](http://api.jquery.com/text/) inside jQuery that automatticaly escapes HTML.

**EDIT:**

If you just want to escape JS, you could do the following:

```
var a = "<b>This</b><script>aaa</script>";
var escapeHTML = function(a) {
    return a.replace(/&/g,'&').replace(/</g,'<').replace(/>/g,'>');
}

a.replace(re, function (_a){return escapeHTML(_a)});
```

And set using .html() the string that a.replace() returns